# Range slider with ajax in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-ui, laravel-5.3

Has anyone used  JQuery range slider in laravel with ajax ? I have been googling about this for tips almost a month about how to us it in laravel with ajax but could't find one. If any one has used it please share some vison on how to implement it on laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link, here you can get all the important methods and options
[jQuery Range Slider](https://egorkhmelev.github.io/jslider/)

First, you should download and include the script in your page. After that initialize your element with slider as

```
jQuery("#Slider3").slider({ from: 0, to: 500, heterogeneity: ['50/100', '75/250'], scale: [0, '|', 50, '|', '100', '|', 250, '|', 500], limits: false, step: 1, dimension: '&nbsp;m<small>2</small>', skin: "plastic" });
```